# Issues with crop marks

Tags: header-footer, diagrams, templates

I'm using the template of a journal, which can be found here:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/review-of-financial-studies-latex-template/bdgcyvpjqmbc

The header is supposed to have two images in the corners.
[image: This is how it should look]

I think the code for the images is as follows:

```
\begin{picture}(0,0)\unitlength\p@\thinlines
  \put(-30,0){\circle{10}}
  \put(-30,-5){\line(0,1){10}}
  \put(-35,0){\line(1,0){30}}
  \put(0,30){\circle{10}}
  \put(-5,30){\line(1,0){10}}
  \put(0,35){\line(0,-1){30}}
  \end{picture}}
```

However, when I compile (for example directly on overleaf, or in texniccenter, or in texstudio) the images don't show up. Instead, I get the text that corresponds to the code, in an overflown line.

Any idea of what may be going on and how to fix it?

Thank you in advance.[image: The image I get]

Comment: Hi there. Tom from Overleaf Support here. Sorry for being late into the party. I just discovered this issue, and we'll have a look at it to see how to best correct this. At the very least, we can set that template to open in an older version of TeX Live. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The two small images (actually there should be four) in the corners are crop marks. Your attached image looks very like the `cam` crop mark created by [`crop`](https://ctan.org/pkg/crop) package.

In the following example, the printed area is a4paper (set by `geometry` package), but the physical area is 250mm x 337mm (which is wider and higher than printed area by 40mm, respectively).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[cam,center,width=250mm,height=337mm]{crop}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also see

- [How to create crop marks](https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-crop), TeX-FAQ

Comment: Thank you. The crop reference is very useful. I copied your code in a new overleaf file, and I get a similar issue: the top of the page shows the text picture(0,0)(-30,0)(10) (-30,-5)(0,1)(10) etc. Also overflown. Any idea how to fix the issue? Thank you very much again.

Comment: @user222431 For your own safety, don't work on overleaf. Their TeX distribution is out-of-date most of the time which caused me a lot of issues before.

Comment: I have the same issue in texniccenter and texstudio. If you have any idea what in particular is out-of-date and creating this issue that would be helpful.

Comment: @user222431 I've tested the example in my answer on overleaf, choosing texlive 2019 and using either of pdflatex, xelatex, and lualtex. Each of them works as expected, hence I cannot reproduce your problem. Can you share an overleaf link?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, here is the link, you should be able to edit. https://www.overleaf.com/5944726911pgvnknyvsjcx

Comment: @user222431 I think the problem will disappear if you delete all the `.sty` and `.def` files from the overleaf project. For example, the latest `crop` is 2017/11/19 v1.10, but you uploaded 2001/11/16 v1.6 which didn't support package options `width` and `height` yet. It there any particular reason that you need to upload and use your own version of packages?

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. I am supposed to use the RFS template, and that one comes with the crop file saved in there. I noticed that if I replace the crop.sty currently saved with the new crop.sty then the cropping just disappears entirely. This is the link to the template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/review-of-financial-studies-latex-template/bdgcyvpjqmbc I wonder if this is an issue with the version of the files. The template on overleaf is the same version as the most up to date version of the template on the publishers website.

Comment: @user222431 I find texlive 2018 on overleaf works for Review of Financial Studies LaTeX template.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much. If works very well now!